# About detecting dragging in extjs window component

Tags: javascript, extjs

I use this code

```
    win = Ext.create('widget.window', {
            title: 'Layout Window',
            closable: true,
            closeAction: 'hide',
            width: 600,
            minWidth: 350,
            height: 350,
            layout: {
                type: 'border',
                padding: 5
            },
            listeners : {
                render : function(){
                    alert("render");
                },
                beforerender : function(){
                    alert("beforerender");
                },
                afterrender : function(){
                    alert("afterrender");
                }
            },

            items: [...

            ]
        });
    win.on('move',function(){
        alert("ddd");
    });
```

to detect movement of the window component in extjs. It works well i.e it alerts "ddd" but that happens after I move the window and stop dragging it.

I would like to detect when the dragging of the window starts, i.e when I press with cursor on the window title bar and start to drag.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event you want to bind to if you want to tap into each drag movement is 'drag'.

```
win.on('move',function(){
    console.log("ddd", arguments);
});
```

Other available drag events include dragstart and dragend.

For more detail see:
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.dd.DragTracker-event-drag